# Calculating scale and position for stretching an object sideways

Tags: c++, resize, geometry, transform, scaling

I'm trying to implement object stretching through the use of a selection bounding box, in 2D orthographic views of 3D space. The type of effect I'm trying to get is like when an object is surrounded with a selection marquee, and the sides and corners can be pulled to change the underlying objects shape.

**My problem is that I can't get the math for this right.**

The only way I could think of for achieving stretching towards only the mouse would be to perform 2 steps:

- 1) Scale the object half way towards the mouse position (since a full scale would also scale the opposite side of the object)
- 2) Translate the object the second half of the way

This should result in scaling the object **towards** the mouse, while keeping the opposing edge "locked" in position:

[image]

### Problem:

I've managed to implement a really crappy version of this, but it only works for squared shapes (gif above), or more precisely, *shapes which have a maximum width/height/depth that are all the same.* Otherwise, this happens:

[image]

### Details:

My objects aren't 2D, they are 3D but displayed on 2D orthographic views. They don't have an origin point at their bottom left edge, their origin point can be anywhere within it, and any mesh is possible.

Here's how I try to calculate the scale and position from the mouse coordinate.
This chunk is used for RIGHT, TOP, and FRONT faces

```
//target = mouse position
//objPos = object origin position
//objScale = object's current scale
//min and max = the furthest edges of the mesh, on this axis, scaled
float difference = max - min;

//Get desired scale
float scale = ( target + ( difference/2 )  -objPos ) / (difference/objScale); 

//Get desired position
float scalemax = ( target + ( difference/2 ) - objPos) / difference;
float position = ( ( (difference)/2 ) * ( scalemax ) ) + min; // Gets passed back to the selected object
```

And this chunk is used for the LEFT, BOTTOM, and BACK faces:

```
float diff1 = difference/objScale;
float scale = (difference-(target-min))/diff1;
float diff2 = diff1*scale;
float diff3 = max-((diff2/2)+objPos);
float position = diff3+objPos;
```

So what I'm looking for is a proper way to calculate scale and position for an object given a mouse coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me quite a bit of time, but I eventually figured it out,

In order to calculate the appropriate scale, I had to multiply the leftmost edge multiplied by the current scale added to the current position, subtracted by the current mouse coordinate. Finally, all that divided by the base width or difference between the most extreme points for that object on that particular axis.

For the position I did the same thing by multiplying the left most edge by the current scale added to the current position, but then subtracted by the left most edge multiplied by the newly calculated scale added to the current position. Then this value would be an offset position, to be added to the current object position.

```
float scale = (target-((baseMin*objScale)+objPos))/baseDifference;
float position = (((baseMin*objScale)+objPos)-((baseMin*scale)+objPos))+objPos;
```

For example, if the object is a cube, and the right side of the cube is to be stretched, lets say from 50 units all the way to 250 units, or a 3 times scale increase:

```
base difference = rightmost edge - leftmost edge
base difference = (50) - (-50) = 100;

scale = (250 - ( (-50 * 1) + 0) ) / 100;
scale = (300) / (100) = 3; 

position = (( (-50 * 1) + 0 ) - ((-50 * 3) + 0) ) + 0;
position = (-50) - (-150) = 100;
```

This works with any shape with any size, with an origin point ANYWHERE within it. The only thing that has to change is the minimum and maximum depending on which edge is used.

[image]